# SQL Server: Help in writing a query to get 3 rolling months average for a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Query Thus far:

```
select month
     , year
     , vol
     --, sum(vol) over (order by month,year  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND current row) sumnetvol,
     , avg(vol) over ( order by  month,year  
                       ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING 
                                AND current row) '3monthra'
     , name
     , cnt
     , costx  
from (
    SELECT month(convert(datetime, cast(monthnumber as nvarchar(10))+'01')) as [Month]
         , year(convert(datetime,cast(monthnumber as nvarchar(10))+'01')) as [Year]
         , sum(SumOfNetAmount) as vol
         , count(*) as cnt
         , costx
         , name 
    FROM [ngl_OTB] 
    GROUP BY costx
           , MONTH(convert(datetime,cast(monthnumber as nvarchar(10))+'01'))
           , YEAR(convert(datetime,cast(monthnumber as nvarchar(10))+'01'))
           , name
           , SumOfNetAmount
) s 
where costx = '1000.002' and 
 name = 'ngl-raw' 
order by month,year
```

I need help on how to recursively set the [costx] and [name] columns to allow 3 months rolling avg of each [costx] and [name] correctly. All attempts provided wrong calculations like 3 months rolling avg was bleeding into other costx and name. 
My goal is to group all the data by costx and name and order by year and month, then performing a rolling 3 months avg on each costx using the value of [vol] for that [costx]

Any help will be greatly apppreciated

Comment: It is better if you write an answer and accept it. You wont get any points for accepting your own answer but it can be upvoted by others (I will).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select month
     , year
     , vol
   --, sum(vol) over (partition by costx, name order by month,year ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND current row) sumnetvol,
     , avg(vol) over (partition by costx, name order by month,year ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND current row) '3monthra'
     , name
     , cnt
     , costx                                                                       
from (
SELECT month(convert(datetime, cast(monthnumber as nvarchar(10))+'01')) as [Month]
     , year(convert(datetime,cast(monthnumber as nvarchar(10))+'01')) as [Year]
     , sum(SumOfNetAmount) as vol
     , count(*) as cnt
     , costx
     , name 
FROM [ngl_OTB] 
GROUP BY costx
       , MONTH(convert(datetime,cast(monthnumber as nvarchar(10))+'01'))
       , YEAR(convert(datetime,cast(monthnumber as nvarchar(10))+'01'))
       , name
       , SumOfNetAmount)s 
where costx = '1000.002' and name = 'ngl-raw' order by month,year
```